# Subversion Connection: RA layer request failed

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

Out of the blue yesterday afternoon, subversion connections from my Eclipse IDE to our Subversion repository have been failing (with both Subversive and Subclipse).

I can browse the subversion directory via the browser and it only connections via Eclipse that are failing (I am using a MacBook Prod Mountain Lion OSX 10.8.1; latest Java from Apple 1.6.0)

Message receive when attempting subversion connection:

"RA layer request failed
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://example.com/tags/project': Could not read status line: Connection reset by peer (http://example.com)"

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to browse the repository, or do you have an existing working copy you are trying to update?  I think you are probably not entering a proper SVN repository URL.  Just because the browser is working, does not mean that is the right URL for the client.  It *might* be.  It depends whether you are browsing the repository directly or using a web GUI.

The problem could also be related to a proxy server.  If you need a proxy server, odds are that your web browser is already configured to use it.  However, SVN clients have their own configuration for proxies that has to be configured separately.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Mark. It was helpful and I went through the checklist to isolate causes but no luck so far. Others in my team do not have problems accessing. I have since also tried using 'svn' from the command line and I am getting same error. I have no problem if I try to access from another computer - it seems to be something to do with my MacBook that is causing the connection failure: I am stumped!